# AWS API Gateway exported IOS SDK no error response

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, httpresponse, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am using the exported API Gateway IOS SDK. The API was originally imported to the API Gateway via Swagger as a template, but since modified with the AWS portal to map back to the response model and class within the IOS SDK. All 200 requests are returned with no issue. I am using pod 'AWSAPIGateway', '= 2.4.1'

The issue i am having is nothing else other then 200 response is handled and/or received by the IOS SDK. I know it is sent because Cloudwatch shows the correct mapping, but nothing is returned in the IOS App.

At first i thought maybe i was conflicting with the API Gateway's own response codes so i switched to 403 which wasn't on it list. But that didn't work. I am also not getting 500 response errors.

Here is the calling function:

```
   client.apiRequestPut(apiRequestVar).continueWithSuccessBlock {
        (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

        print(task)

        if ((task.error) != nil) {
            print(task.error)

            return nil;
        }
        if( (task.result != nil)) {

            print(task.result)

            }

        }

        return nil
    }
```

And the AWS SDK Generated Client Function:

```
 - (AWSTask *)apiRequestPut:(APINewRequest *)body {
           NSDictionary *headerParameters = @{
                                        @"Content-Type": @"application/json",
                                   @"Accept": @"application/json",

                                   };
NSDictionary *queryParameters = @{

                                  };
NSDictionary *pathParameters = @{

                                 };

return [self invokeHTTPRequest:@"PUT"
                     URLString:@"/requestVariable"
                pathParameters:pathParameters
               queryParameters:queryParameters
              headerParameters:headerParameters
                          body:body
                 responseClass:[APIModel class]];
 }
```

}

Here is the Error Model:

```
  @implementation APIErrorModel

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
           @"success": @"success",
           @"theFunction": @"theFunction",
           @"action": @"action",
           @"timeStamp": @"timeStamp",
           @"error": @"error",
           @"data": @"data"
           };
  }

 + (NSValueTransformer *)timeStampJSONTransformer {
    return [AWSMTLValueTransformer     reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^id(NSString *dateString) {
       return [NSDate aws_dateFromString:dateString   format:AWSDateISO8601DateFormat1];
     } reverseBlock:^id(NSDate *date) {
        return [date aws_stringValue:AWSDateISO8601DateFormat1];
    }];
```

}

Here is the mapping in the API Gateway for 400 response code:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
 {
    "success" : $input.json('$.success'),
    "theFunction" : "foo",
    "action" : "foo",
    "timeStamp" : "foo",
    "error" : "foo",
    "data" : $input.json('$.message')
}
```

Here is the resulting Cloudwatch log entry:

```
  Endpoint response body before transformations:
 {
   "success": false,
       "message": "{\"message\":\"The conditional request     failed\",\"code\":\"ConditionalCheckFailedException\",\"time\":\"2016-05-    12T20:16:03.165Z\",\"statusCode\":400,\"retryable\":false,\"retryDelay\":0}     "
 }
  Endpoint response headers: {content-length=217, Connection=keep-alive,     content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, cache-control=no-cache,   Date=Thu, 12 May 2016 20:16:03 GMT
}

  Method response body after transformations:
  {
    "success": false,
    "theFunction": "foo",
    "action": "foo",
    "timeStamp": "foo",
    "error": "foo",
    "data": "{\"message\":\"The conditional request     failed\",\"code\":\"ConditionalCheckFailedException\",\"time\":\"2016-05-  12T20:16:03.165Z\",\"statusCode\":400,\"retryable\":false,\"retryDelay\":0}  "
}

Method response headers: {Content-Type=application/json}
Successfully completed execution
Method completed with status: 400
```

But then i get nothing received back in the iOS app?

Any help to what i am missing would be much appreciated!

Comment: You want to consider exporting to Swagger spec and then use [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate the ObjC SDK (which comes with auto-generated doc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- continueWithSuccessBlock:` is used when you want to extract only the `result` from the task object. The `task` object in `- continueWithSuccessBlock:` always has the `nil` `error` property. If you want to receive errors, you need to use `- continueWithBlock:` instead.

See the [Bolts](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC#tasks) documentation for more details.

Comment: That was it! If it was a snake it would have bit me